# 2D Array output 'back and forth' effect

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make my 2D array output so that every second line outputs from right to left.

For instance just outputting normally would look like this:

```
0.5       0.62      0.35      0.6       0.5       
0.45      0.62      0.25      0.25      0.13      
0.65      0.85      0.2       0.2       0.8
```

but outputting every second line from right to left would look like this:

```
0.5        0.62       0.35       0.6       0.5 
0.13       0.25       0.25       0.62      0.45 
0.65       0.85       0.2        0.2       0.8
```

so the second line is outputting from right to left.

Here is my code so far:

```
int k = 0;
double[][] cd = new double[3][5];
    while (k < gridArr.length){
        for(int i = 0; i < cd.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < cd[i].length; j++){
                cd[i][j] = (double) gridArr[k];
                System.out.print(String.format("%-10s" ,cd[i][j]));
                k++;
                if(j == cd[1].length-1) {
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

What could I do to get this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
int k = 0;
double[][] cd = new double[3][5];
    while (k < gridArr.length){
        for(int i = 0; i < cd.length; i++){
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                for(int j = 0; j < cd[i].length; j++){
                    cd[i][j] = (double) gridArr[k];
                    System.out.print(String.format("%-10s" ,cd[i][j]));
                    k++;
                    if(j == cd[1].length-1) {
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for(int j = cd[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--){
                    cd[i][j] = (double) gridArr[k];
                    System.out.print(String.format("%-10s" ,cd[i][j]));
                    k++;
                    if(j == cd[1].length-1) {
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For every odd case things happen exactly as before, as for every pair case the for is inversed.

Comment: I get the error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` after the for loop inside of the `else`

Comment: Thank you for the observation, I have started that one from cd[i].length, but I should have started it from cd[i].length - 1. Check out the edited code.

Comment: My output still hasn't changed.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

I wrote it as unit test class, but you got the idea, I think it is pretty straightforward.

```
@Test
public void test2dArray() {
    double[][] arr = {
            {0.5, 0.62, 0.35, 0.6, 0.5},
            {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {0.65, 0.85, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8},
            {10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
            {0.65, 0.85, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8},
            {100, 200, 300, 400, 500},
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            for (int j = arr[i].length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                System.out.printf("%-10s", arr[i][j]);
        } else {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
                System.out.printf("%-10s", arr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

output:

```
0.5       0.62      0.35      0.6       0.5       
5.0       4.0       3.0       2.0       1.0       
0.65      0.85      0.2       0.2       0.8       
50.0      40.0      30.0      20.0      10.0      
0.65      0.85      0.2       0.2       0.8       
500.0     400.0     300.0     200.0     100.0
```